# Static order initialization fiasco, iostream and C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, static, iostream, static-order-fiasco

According to C++11 specification:

> The results of including `<iostream>` in a translation unit shall be as if `<iostream>` defined an instance of `ios_base::Init` with static storage duration. Similarly, the entire program shall behave as if there were at least
>   one instance of `ios_base::Init` with static storage duration

This implies that if my code looks like that:

```
// A.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
unsigned long foo() {
    cerr << "bar"; 
    return 42;
}
```

and

```
// B.cpp

using namespace std;
extern unsigned long foo();

namespace {
unsigned long test() {
    int id = foo();
    return id;
}

unsigned long id = test();
}


int main() {
     return 0;
}
```

then I should be safe calling `cerr` without the risk of a static initialization fiasco.

Unfortunately, that code segfaults... Why? I don't think gcc 6.2.1 decided to ignore the C++11 specification, and I included `<iostream>` in A.cpp. According to the specification it should suffice.

Comment: Please the exact code that exactly segfaults.

Comment: Done (15 chars)

Comment: This doesn't even compile.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Now it should compile

Comment: The return type of `foo` doesn't match up. `int` versus `unsigned long`. Is that relevant?

Comment: Not relevant to this problem but fixed.

Comment: Also, it still doesn't compile. You forgot `std::` in front of `cerr`. Sorry to be pedantic, but it helps to provide the actual code

Comment: Done. thanks (15 chars)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The full quote of the paragraph includes:

> The objects are constructed and the associations are established at some time prior to or during the first
>   time an object of class ios_base::Init is constructed, and in any case before the body of main begins
>   execution. 293)

And with the footnote

> 293) If it is possible for them to do so, implementations are encouraged to initialize the objects earlier than required.

So, the guarantee is that the iostreams will work *at the latest* when entering main. There is no strict requirement that they should work earlier, unless the translation unit includes `<iostream>`.

You have found a way to circumvent this!

When calling `foo()` from B.cpp, the `ios_base::Init` instance included in A.cpp may, or may not, have been initialized.

Comment: So it would have worked if I explicitly included `<iostream>` in `B.cpp`?